# Copying values from one Infopath user field to another

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

There is three user fields on my form: two contact field and AssignedTo field. How do I copy value from one of the contact fields to AssignedTo field? I've tried copying DisplayName fields, AccountID fields and Type fields but it doesn't work in my case - the AssignedTo field remains empty when I open the form and press the button.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your issue correctly, I assume AssignedTo field is a textbox?

You need to select the AssignedTo field and assign the default value to DisplayName of the 1st contact field.

Please correct me if I misunderstood your issue

EDIT:

on your AssignedTo field. Set the default values of DisplayName, AccountID and AccountType based on the 1st contact field. Tried it and it worked on me after I select a person on my 1st contact field. The AssignedTo field copied it.

Comment: It's a UserPicker field

Comment: Did you try doing it as a button action? It works for me as default values, but it doesn't when I try to do it with a button.

Comment: All right... it seems it started working all by itself, lol :D